# How to calculate the current index?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have written an algorithm which iteratively solves the problem. The first iteration consists of 6 steps and all the following iterations consist of 5 steps (first step is skipped).

What I want to calculate is the current (local) step in the iteration from current global step.

For example if there are 41 steps in total which means there are 8 iterations:
indices from 1 to 6 belong to 1st iteration
indices from 7 to 11 belong to second iteration
...

For calculating the current iteration I have written the following code:

```
if(currentStep <= 6)
        iteration = 1;
    else
        iteration = floor((currentStep - 7)/5) + 2;
    end
```

The problem remains in calculating local steps.
in first iteration the performed steps are: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
in all the following iterations the performing steps are 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

So what has to be done is to transform the array of global steps

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ... 41]
```

into array of local steps

`[1 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 ... 6]`.

I would appreciate if anyone could help in finding the solution to a given problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution in python:

```
L = range(1,42) # so L = [1,2,...,41]
s = [(i-2)%5+2 for i in L]
# adjust for the first step:
s[0]=1
# now s = [1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,...,5,6]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
local_step = [1 mod([0:39],5)+2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
if(currentStep <= 6)  
{localStep = currentStep;}  
else  
{localStep = currentStep - ((iteration - 1) * 5);}
```

Comment: There's a button for code formatting. Also, there's a button with a question mark where you find all the explanations.